# Passport-SAML. How to avoid calling getSamlOptions after authentication on external IdP?

Tags: node.js, passport.js, saml, saml-2.0, passport-saml

Try to setup Passport-SAML on my project. Here is an code example

```
export const samlFederationAuthentication = () => {
  const multiSamlStrategy: MultiSamlStrategy = new MultiSamlStrategy(
    {
      passReqToCallback: true,
      getSamlOptions: async (req: Express.Request, done: SamlOptionsCallback) => {
        const entityID: string = decodeURIComponent((req.query.entityID as string) || '');

        if (!entityID) {
          return done(
            CustomError(
              'Not supported',
              'SAML AUTH',
              `EntityID is undefined`
            )
          );
        }

        const config = await samlFederation.getConfig(); // getting entrypoint and certificate

        if (!config[entityID]) {
          return done(
            CustomError(
              'Not supported',
              'SAML AUTH',
              `EntityID is not supported by IDp`
            )
          );
        }

        return done(null, {
          ...config[entityID],
          callbackUrl: envConfig.samlFederation.callbackURL,
          issuer: envConfig.samlFederation.issuer,
        });
      },
    },
    async (req: Express.Request, profile, done) => {
      try {
        const profileUsername: string = samlFederation.getProfileUsername(profile || {});

        if (!profileUsername) {
          return done(
            CustomError(
              'Username and email are undefined',
              'SAML AUTH',
              `Username or email should be defined in SAML profile`
            )
          );
        }

        const dbUser = await userService.getUserByUsername(profileUsername);

        if (!!dbUser) {
          return done(null, dbUser);
        }


        const createdUser: IUser = await userService.createUser(profile || {});

        return done(null, createdUser as Record<string, any>);
      } catch (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
    }
  );

  Passport.use('multi-saml', multiSamlStrategy);
};
```

and routes:

```
export const addSamlFederationRoutes = (app: Express.Application) => {
  app.get('/auth/saml', Passport.authenticate('multi-saml'));
  app.post(
    '/auth/saml/callback',
    Passport.authorize('multi-saml', { failureRedirect: '/', failureFlash: true }),
    userHandler // some handler with user data
  );
};
```

So now I describe my problem.

1. Users go to federation form and choose some special IdP they wanted to authenticate
2. Federation form sends a request to our server `GET /auth/saml` with EntityID in query of external IdP.
3. Our server looks in database required config params and redirect user to IdP form.

When users go to IdP and enter their credentials then they redirected to our server with url `auth/saml/callback`. It's great but we call middleware `passport.authorize` that lead to calling function `getSamlOptions` in MultiSamlStrategy. But IdP doesn't send me `entityID` in params and my function always send error `Entity ID is undefined`. So, my question is how to avoid calling `getSamlOptions` after authenticating on IdP.

Answer (score 1):

I had to recently implement `MultiSamlStrategy` and was able to get it working without avoiding the second call to `getSamlOptions` by using the `RelayState` of the `saml` configuration. Initially, I used a query variable 'org' to designate which configuration to use. I passed in the parameter that identified the entity into the `RelayState` variable. Then on the second call, used the `RelayState` to correctly route to the intended configuration. Here is an example:

```
passport.use('saml', new MultiSamlStrategy(
    {
        passReqToCallback: true, // makes req available in callback
        getSamlOptions: function (request, done) {
            var config;
            var org;

            if (request.query.org) {
                org = request.query.org;
                request.query.RelayState = JSON.stringify({ProviderName: request.query.org});

            } else {
                const relayState = JSON.parse(request.body.RelayState);
                org = relayState.ProviderName;
            }  

            if (org == "config1" ) {
                config = {
                    issuer: "http://localhost:80",
                    protocol: 'http://',
                    path: '<whatever path you setup>',
                    entryPoint: '<config1 entry point URL>',
                    cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert1.pem','utf-8'),
                    additionalParams: { 'RelayState': request.query.org }
                }
            } else if (org == "config2") {
                config = {
                    issuer: "http://localhost:80",
                    protocol: 'http://',
                    path: '<whatever path you setup>',
                    entryPoint: '<config2 entry point URL>',
                    cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert2.pem', 'utf-8'),
                    additionalParams: { 'RelayState': request.query.org }
                }
            }
            done(null, config);
        }
    },
    function (req, profile, done) {
        // for signon
        done(null, profile)
    },
    function (req, profile, done) {
        // for logout
        done(null, profile)
    }
));
```